# Derivative of a random number

Tags: random-variables

I would like to numerically solve a differential equation which contains a derivative of a random number (using a finite difference method with a time step $\Delta t$).

Let say I need to solve for $y(t)$ in
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t) + A\frac{d}{dt}y(t) + By(t) = f(t) + C\frac{d}{dt}\xi_1(t) +  D\xi_2(t)$$
where $\xi_1(t)$ and $\xi_2(t)$ is a random Gaussian variable (mean = 0, s.d. = 1). $A,B,C,D$ are constants and $f(t)$ is a known function of time.

Please could anyone tell what is the proper numerical treatment for the term $\frac{d}{dt}\xi_1(t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\xi_1(t)$ is independent of $\xi_1(t')$ for $t\neq t'$ then $\xi_1(t)$ is not continuous so the integral over a given step size $\Delta t$ its derivative is meaningless.  So for your equation to make sense $\xi_1(t)$ has to be a continuous function of $t$.
($\xi_1(t)$ need not be differentiable, just as $\xi_2(t)$ need not be continuous for the equation to have meaning.  )

So if you let $\xi_1(t)$ be something like a Weiner distribution (perhaps modified to have some asymmetric drift depending on $t$), then the problem is meaningful.  And now your contribution, in a step of size $\Delta t$,  will be the usual
$$
\frac{\xi_1(t+\Delta t)- \xi_1(t)}{\Delta t}
$$ 
To work with a second-order method, it will be necessary for $\xi_1(t)$ to also be differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The Gaussian noise I was talking to is indeed discrete. I guess I need to study my problem more thoroughly and look for a more suitable random variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if $\xi_1(t)$ has $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distribution $\forall t$, than $\xi_1(t)$ is white noise, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Statistical_properties). 
But Gaussian white noise for continuous time **does not even exist** as a classical random variable! It is only weak random variable.

I think what you look for is theory of stochastic differential equation, many books could be found about this, [example about SPDE](http://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf), but you will have to learn the whole new theory about it and how to solve it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It seems that my random variables I was talking are in fact discrete. I may have to use other type of continuous randon variables inorder to properly solve my problem.